# How to access jquery function properties from event

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, jquery-events

Using jQuery and coffeescript, if I have the following html:

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

and the following coffeescript:

```
button = $('<div>Click here</div>')
button.some_var = "secret message"
button.on "click", ->
    alert this.some_var
$('#main').html button
```

This doesn't work.  Is there any way to get it to work?  Or any other way to have the click event of a particular element given access to the properties of a particular Javascript function?

Comment: `button` is a jQuery object, `this` is a DOM element. They are not the same objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store data on the jQuery object.

```
button = $ '<div>Click here</div>'

button.data 'some_var', 'secret message'

button.on 'click', ->
    alert $(@).data 'some_var'
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q88h9gou)

Comment: Or `$(this)` instead of `button`.

Comment: @FelixKling Good point, i think that would make it clearer as well.

Comment: OK. should this work if the data is an object, not a string?  I am not getting it to work.  Specifically I am trying to do: ```this.data('mpclubSource').start(0)``` where the data is an AudioBufferSourceNode

Comment: @JesseGoodfellow: Similar problem there, `this` inside the event handler refers to the **DOM element**. `.data()` is a **jQuery** method. Maybe have a look at http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/

Answer (score 3):

The context of a jQuery bound method is set to **the DOM element** which triggered the event. You set the property `.some_var` against the jQuery Object, not the DOM Element Node.

If you want to store the property against the element, you could do:

```
button.get(0).somevar = "secret message"
```

As commented by @Kyle - if you want to simply *associate* data with an element, it might be best to use the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method on a jQuery Object, which allows for a key-value store without manipulating the native Element.